# Failed to load JNI shared library

Tags: java, eclipse

When I am trying to start my STS editor, I received a message as pop-up window
open and said that

> Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin...\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll

Here i am posting my STS.ini below.

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
–launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
com.springsource.sts.ide
–launcher.defaultAction
openFile
–launcher.XXMaxPermSize
384M
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xmn128m
-Xms256m
-Xmx768m
-Xss4m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m
-XX:CompileThreshold=1000
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
```

Comment: Welcome to programmers. This kind of question is off topic.

Answer (score 6):

I am using Windows 7 64bit and my eclipse was 32 bit. i face the problem showing this message when want to open my eclipse

```
Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin...\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

now i install 32bit JVM from below link and install it.

http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

Then i just set PATH from Environment variables

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin
```

Now it's work for me!!!

Comment: +1 for pointing out this is a 64 vs 32-bit issue. Instead of changing my JDK, I downloaded the 64-bit version of eclipse. Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The -vm option must specify the full absolute or relative path to the **Java executable**, not just to the Java home directory. In Windows that would be:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\javaw.exe
```

Also I would move the `-vm` option to be immediately before the `-vmargs` option:

```
...
–launcher.XXMaxPermSize
384M
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
...
```

More details can be found here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the jdk version to 1.8 or above. It works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).